# [Python][Selenium]Unable to use webdriver with Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

I'm a beginner in Python and Selenium, and I dont know what is the error in my code or environment...

```
# encoding: utf-8
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Python27/Scripts/chromedriver') 
time.sleep(3)
driver.get('https://www.google.com.tw/')   
for i in range(10):  
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')  
    time.sleep(1)  
    print ("Scrolling...")
driver.close()
```

And here is error messages...

> C:\Python27\python.exe D:/PythonPratice/test.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "D:/PythonPratice/test.py", line 9, in 
>       driver.get('https://www.google.com.tw/')
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 250, in get
>       self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"2172.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>     (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Much thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to download [latest version of `chromedriver`](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.28/) and put it to `C:/Python27/Scripts/` instead of outdated one

Comment: Thanks ur answer, but I cannot download it from this site.... Is this my problem?

Answer (score 1):

you should provide full path of `chromedriver.exe`, see the following:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:/Python27/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: no need to provide the path explicitly if chromedriver is located somewhere on your system path

Comment: source code is saying `- executable_path - path to the executable. If the default is used it assumes the executable is in the $PATH`, check https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ceaf3da79542024becdda5953059dfbb96fb3a90/py/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py

Comment: that's what my comment said

Comment: thanks for reminding, chrome path is given explicitly in the original question thats why I recommended this.